# c++ : correct way to calculate power for large no

Tags: c++, double

I am trying to calculate 65^17 using c++.
I wrote following code but getting wrong value when 65^11 . 
What is the correct way to calculate the answer ? ( i.e. 65^17)

Code :

```
long double data= 1;
int m_ne=17;
int i_data=65;
for(int i=1;i<= m_ne;i++)
{
     data =  data  * (i_data);
     std::cout.precision(15);
     std::cout<<" "<<std::fixed <<data<<std::endl;
 }
```

output:

```
65.000000000000000
 4225.000000000000000
 274625.000000000000000
 17850625.000000000000000
 1160290625.000000000000000
 75418890625.000000000000000
 4902227890625.000000000000000
 318644812890625.000000000000000
 20711912837890625.000000000000000
 1346274334462890625.000000000000000
 87507831740087890624.000000000000000
```

I tried following options but all in vain

```
1. data = floor( data +0.5) * i_data ;        

2. data = floor( data +0.5) * floor (i_data + 0.5 ) ;        
By declaring i_data as float .

3.
data =  data * i_data ;        
data = floor ( data + 0.5 )
```

I read post about the double but I am not getting solution .

Comment: Support for Quad math is not standard, what is the compiler? Is it GCC?

Comment: Also this: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath.pdf

Answer (score 7):

C++ itself does not support what you are trying to do with its standard data types. You would need at least 104 bits to represent every integer from 0 to 67^17.

If you feel an approximation is good enough for you, the best you can do is use the `long double` version of the included power function:

```
#include <cmath>
```

and

```
::std::cout << ::std::powl(65, 17) << ::std::endl;
```

You will not get a correct output however, since 65^17 is odd (the last decimal digit is a 5), and therefore would require a floating point type with at least a 104 bit mantissa (which `long double` usually does not have).

To get a correct answer, will need to use an higher precision library, such as [GMP](http://gmplib.org/), which has types that can hold way more than the 104 bits you reqire and provides its own, fast exponentiation functions like [this](http://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Exponentiation.html#Integer-Exponentiation).

Answer (score 0):

There is the pow function. http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/pow/:

Just include

```
#include <math.h>
```

or

```
 #include <cmath>
```

And then

```
pow(65,17);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use Bignum library `gmp` to handle large data types which can't be handled by standard c++ types. http://gmplib.org/